# How to diff specific files in Git?

Tags: git

I need to include only specific files (either by the list or by regex/wildcard pattern) in

> git diff -R origin/master

Use case: I've ported an app to a different programming language, the original repository has changed since and I need to see changes only for the *.cc and *.h files, excluding the rest (which are plenty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use patterns without problems. Example: `git diff -- '*.c'` That goes through subdirectories.

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out. For some reason, enclosing pattern in single quotes didn't work for me on Windows, but it did work without quotes, like this: 
git diff -R origin/master *.cc *.h
I realize that my question is a duplicate, but still leaving it here because the accepted answer in the original question didn't work for me